# How to use the power of in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given something to calculate in the context charges of gas energy.
The formula used is `0.8617 x SOQ ^ -0.2155` the SOQ can vary. I am just wondering, how can this be done on SQL? What formula or functions can be used to accomplished this ?

Comment: there is a function `power` that you can use.

Comment: *SOQ is the cold winter capacity of Gas

Comment: Hello. Could you please accept the correct answer? Do you know how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 0.8617 * POWER(SOQ, -0.2155) AS [Result]
```

where `SOQ` is your value

To find out more about `POWER()` see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use as below:

```
declare @soq int
update table1 set val = power((0.8617*@soq),-0.2155)
```